# How should private network services be exposed to users using DNS over HTTPS?

Tags: domain-name-system

As DNS over HTTPS becomes more widely deployed, I am starting to hear reports that users are failing to access services from internal networks when DNS over HTTPS is turned on.

Fair enough, DNS over HTTPS goes to Cloudflare or other public DNS services, not touching my internal DNS infrastructure. So it is understandable that it fails to resolve services in my private network.

Interestingly, the behavior appears to differ between versions of Firefox, for example. In the latest beta, one user reports that internal services are accessible even when DNS over HTTPS is enabled.

Clearly, private networks do exist and browser authors are taking them into consideration. However, I am not able to find any documentation about it. What should I as a private network operator do to ensure that users in my network who use DNS over HTTPS still are able to resolve services exposed by my private DNS servers?

Comment: [I see there's a setting](https://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-enable-dns-over-https-doh-in-firefox/) `network.trr.mode` that controls whether Firefox uses DOH *instead of* or *in addition to* the ordinary DNS.  Perhaps the users that are reporting different results have configured this setting differently?

Comment: "What should I as a private network operator do to ensure that users in my network who use DNS over HTTPS still are able to resolve services exposed by my private DNS servers?". Easy: gently ask your users to configure their browsers accordingly and switch off this Firefox nonsense that is now enabled by default. Or use Firefox group/entreprise policies.Hard: filter DOH. It is hard because DOH was created exactly to be silently hidden into any other HTTPS stream. Which is exactly why it irritates people when browsers switch it on automatically without consideration for local policies.